# Parameter of Conditional Gaussian Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian

I'd like to understand how to determine the parameter of **conditional gaussian distribution**. Following is the network architecture of [**VUNET**](https://compvis.github.io/vunet/images/vunet.pdf) which learns the conditional gaussian distribution $q(z|x, \hat y)$ of **appearance of human($z$)** upon given two conditional inputs **skeleton of body pose** **and groundTruth image($x$)** of 128x128 resolution image

[image: vunet architecture]

I don't understand how $2\times2\times256$ vector and 
$1\times1$ vector can characterize  $q(z|x, \hat y)$. Any advice to understand this point clearly?